# Source for a downloadable dictionary with IPA phonetic transcriptions?

Tags: discussion

I have an idea for a fun challenge but it will require access to IPA phonetic transcriptions (in English at least). An API that serves up the same would also do, though it would tend to favor languages with integrated support for external APIs.

Web searching has not revealed any such dictionaries to me, but it feels like one should exist. Can anybody point me to such a dictionary or word list?

Comment: Have you looked at wiktionary?  I know it has an API and IPA, but I don't know much about the API.

Comment: While I'm not opposed to people using Meta to find resources to make good challenges, I do think that asking in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) first, *then* asking on Meta if chat doesn't help is usually a better strategy (for future reference)

Comment: There's `espeak --ipa` for offline API (although it might be inaccurate). There's also cmudict (it's not IPA but can be converted to) -- but yes I agree that meta is not okay here.

Comment: Remark: if it involves the spelling of the words too, it's definitely going to be prohibitively difficult.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the word and its corresponding IPA, then you can use [open-dict-data/ipa-dict](https://github.com/open-dict-data/ipa-dict). It has files for both American English (en_US) and British English (en_UK) in a number of formats.